# How to Send Streamed UDP Packets to Browser Using SSE in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventsource

I have a node js server that listens to audio that is streamed on a local network using VBAN protocol. VBAN, basically a protocol that sends audio stream over local network using UDP. You can read more about VBAN and it's applications [here](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/vban.htm)

The next step, after receiving the audio from the VBAN, the node js server process the received audio.

Also, the node js server should send the processed packages to the browser, in this case, using EventEmitter, through a GET request:

```
 const EventEmmitter = require("events");
 const stream = new EventEmmitter();

 app.get("/stream", function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    Connection: "keep-alive",
  });

  stream.on("push", function (event, data) {
    res.write(`event: ${event},  data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  });
});
```

In the front-end side, which is an Angular application, receives the data from the server using EventSource

```
   public dataObservable(): Observable<MessageEvent> {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      let eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/stream');
      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        console.log('Received event: ', event);
        const json = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log("audio", json);
        observer.next(json);
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        if (eventSource.readyState === 0) {
          console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
          eventSource.close();
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
        }
      };
    });
  }
```

From the inspector, in the Network, it shows that the browser is receiving the data from the server, but there is no data being emitted from the EventSource.

I'm not sure whether I'm using the wrong approach or I have the wrong implementation of this approach. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to send the processed packages to the front-end side using Socket IO.

Here's the server-side implementation (node js):

first of all, I installed socket.io dependency into node js app:

```
npm install socket.io
```

Then, to initialize the socket.io:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);
```

And here I've configured the HTTP get request, and make the app listing to the specified port:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1>Hey Socket.io</h1>");
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
```

Next, emitting the audio messages using the socket.io

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected");
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("user disconnected");
  });
});

io.on("connection", () => {
  let dgram = require("dgram");
  let server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

  server.on("listening", () => {
    let address = server.address();
    console.log("server host", address.address);
    console.log("server port", address.port);
  });

  server.on("message", function (message, remote) {
    let audioData = vban.ProcessPacket(message);
    io.emit("audio", audioData); // // console.log(`Received packet: ${remote.address}:${remote.port}`)
  });
  server.bind(PORT, HOST);
});
```

In the front-end (Angular):

I've added socket.io dependency into the Angular app:

```
npm install socket.io-client
```

Finally, I've added a listener for my audio event:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  SOCKET_ENDPOINT: 'http://localhost:3000'
};

 setupSocketConnection() {
    var socket = io(environment.SOCKET_ENDPOINT);
    socket.emit('my message', 'Hello there from Angular.');

    socket.on('audio', (audio) => {
      console.log('audio:' ,audio);
      this.playAudio(audio);
    });
  }
```

[Reference](https://medium.com/iamdeepinder/creating-a-real-time-app-with-angular-8-and-socket-io-with-nodejs-af63bd59a47f) to the source which I've used to implement the socket.io

I still want to know if I can use EventEmitter to send the data to the client app.